# Safari No Response + hanging on certain requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, safari, puma

For Safari Mac, in the local server and on the remote server, a certain request just hangs without a response from the server. The same request works perfectly on Chrome.

Some answers suggest that it might have to do with the timeout and how safari handles it or how many requests can happen at once. Is there any work-around on the rails side that might fix it?

I'm not sure if it's the xhr request specifically or the combination with the other two png downloads.

[image]

The 3 pending requests

[image]